# Rest API Unit Testing Using Moq

Tags: rest, unit-testing, moq

How to test Rest API..?

In my project we have mocked data access layer. In unit test via end point will hit business layer and it returns the same value which has been mocked.

Since, our unit test will always pass as we have mocked then what is the use of unit testing..?

Let me know if there are any better ways of testing rest end points.

Answer (score 0):

Since, our unit test will always pass as we have mocked then what is the use of unit testing..?

Ans: If you are passing x json and expect y json. Its not just magically returned in response, You have written some business layer where you perform some logic.
In you case that operation is working fine if your test is returning expected data.

Let me know if there are any better ways of testing rest end points.

Ans:Your approach is correct, also read about smoke test